# Percentile difficulty in excel

Tags: excel, excel-formula, excel-2010

I am trying to calculate percentile based on multi criteria but it seems to be completely ignoring my criteria - Help!

Column A - Manager Name 
Column B - Calls Answered

Formulas I have tried:

```
=IF(AS:AS=AS2,IF(G2<PERCENTILE.EXC(G:G,33.33333%),"Bottom",IF(G2<PERCENTILE.EXC(G:G,66.66666%),"Middle","Upper")))
```

Also used:

```
=IF(AND(AS:AS=AS2,B:B=B2,G2<PERCENTILE.EXC(G:G,33.33333%)),"Bottom",IF(AND(AS:AS=AS2,B:B=B2,G2<PERCENTILE.EXC(G:G,66.66666%)),"Middle","Upper"))
```

Comment: what are you trying to do with this`=IF(AS:AS=AS2,` ? It is not correct as it stands so I am try understand your thinking.

Comment: The AS column has the managers names. So I'm trying for it to look at everything in column AS and equal AS2 that a managers name is in. Hope that makes sense

Comment: Showing the data you are working with and expected result would help.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use this:

```
=IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/(AS$2:AS$1000=AS2),.3333333),"Bottom",IF(G2<AGGREGATE(18,6,G$2:G$1000/(AS$2:AS$1000=AS2),.66666666),"Middle","Top"))
```

But one note.  One should only use confined date set reference and avoid full column references when using array type formula.

Comment: I have no idea how this works but its workings fine - Trying to make out how this works. Confused

Comment: AGGREGATE is an array type formula.  It allows us to force errors and ignore them.  `18` is `PERCENTILE.EXC` `6` ignore the errors.  So when ever the row in AS does not = AS2 it throws an error that is ignored.  Only the numbers in G are used where AS = AS2.

Comment: That's brilliant - Thank you for the help